# Unit root MA process

Tags: unit-root, moving-average

A unit root AR process blows up because white noise is accumulated. Does a unit root MA process also blow up? How can a unit root MA process be stationary, for example, when it can be expressed with AR terms?

Comment: If you consider an MA(1) process$$X_t=\mu+\epsilon_t-\theta\varepsilon_{t-1}$$ with $\epsilon_v\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, when$\theta=1$, the marginal distribution of $X_t$ is a $\mathcal{N}(\mu,2)$ for all $t$'s, hence exhibit stationarity.

Comment: Not that it necessarily matters, since you didn't ask, but the process that Xian describes is not invertible. The error term cannot be written as an infinite sum of previous $X_t$.